# What is the sequence that the numbers are following?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to come with an equation that follows this AP Series or GP Series.

Something like $n(n-1)/2$

This is my series,

$$1+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{4}{5} + \frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{6}{7} + .. $$

Kindly share your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: This is not an AP or GP series, and I suspect that the expression will be quite a bit more complicated than $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$

Comment: @Arthur I believe so, I am trying to program the logic that the sequence follows. New to this type of questions. Thanks.

Comment: They seem to follow the pattern $a_{n}^{}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{2n}{2n+1})$.

Comment: $a_1=1;\;a_2=1+2/3;\;a_3=1+2/3+8/15;\;\ldots$
$$a_n=\frac{2^{2 n+1} n! (n+1)!}{(2 n+1)!}-1$$
It's divergent

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as $F(1)$, where $$F(x)=x + \frac23x^3+\frac23\frac45x^5+\cdots$$
This obeys the differential equation
$$x(xF(x))'= F'(x)-1$$

Comment: If I am not mistaken (or Mathematica failed me), than this can be solved to
$$F(x)=\frac{C-\log\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$
which is not defined at $x=1$. Which fits the statement of Raffaele that the series is divergent

Comment: For $x<1$, with $F(0)=0$, M. Winter's answer becomes $F(x)=\arcsin(x)/\sqrt{1-x^2}$